# Custom Parameter when adding a contact through OutlookServicesClient AddContactAsync?

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I am trying to send a custom id from my web app to owa when adding contacts through OutlookServicesClient and office 365 rest apis. I need to be able to synchronize the data between the two. Is there a way to add an additional parameter in contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API doesn't currently support custom fields. That's something we may add in the future, but for now you'd need to use Exchange Web Services if you need to add custom fields.